# Accuracy is decreased drastically after adding custom loss function

Tags: keras, loss-function, loss

```
def custom_loss(lmbda , regularizer_value):
  def loss(y_true , y_pred):
    return K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true ,y_pred) + lmbda * regularizer_value
  return loss


  model_loss = custom_loss(lmbda= 1 , regularizer_value=regularizer_value)

  model.compile(loss=model_loss,optimizer='adam',metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
```

With categorical cross-entropy accuracy is around 90% but now  it is decreased to 10% even after 100 epochs.

Comment: What is your new loss function? Please add more explanation.

Comment: my new loss function is categorical cross entropy